# Javascript window.location.href not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, javascript

I am trying to redirect to another site (say www.google.com) from a SharePoint site. I tried using `window.location.href` and `window.location.replace` but it doesn't work.

It adds the URL to current page URL and displays a page not found error.

The URL is not replacing th epage, instead it just appends at the end of the current page URL.
[image]

Code:

```
function getItemDetails() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Reports');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededItem), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedItem));        

}

function onQuerySucceededItem(sender, args) {

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        if(oListItem.get_id() == getParameter('ID')){
            web = oListItem.get_item('Web_x0020_Link');
        }

    }
        window.location.href = web;
}

function onQueryFailedItem(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: try `window.location.href = 'https://google.com'` or `window.location.href = '//google.com'`. Both worked for me

Comment: that is what I tried. It is not working

Comment: How are you executing this code? Can you show more code? Also add the browser you are testing with.

Comment: I'm using IE11 and have added the error in my edit

Comment: `window.location.href = 'https://google.com'` paste it in the console of **IE** and let me know the update

Comment: It navigate to google.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31877/discussion-between-atish-dipongkor-and-karthik).

Comment: Are you getting right URL in 'web' ? did you debug it ?

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:** Use `window.open(url);`